# QGIS 2.99 and Quick Maps Plugin

Tags: qgis-plugins

Does Quick Maps plugin still work with QGIS 2.99 or is it no longer supported? I am unable to install from zip. Is there a new plugin that allows access to open source data/aerial imagery?

Error is below...

> An error occurred during execution of following code:
>   pyplugin_installer.instance().installFromZipFile('C:\Users\geogjo\Downloads\quick_map_services-0.19.3.zip')
>
> File "", line 1
>   SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
>
> Python version:
>   3.6.0 (v3.6.0:41df79263a11, Dec 23 2016, 08:06:12) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
>
> QGIS version:
>   2.99.0-Master 'Master', 7cfbb6fb1c
>
> Python path:
>   ['C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.99/apps/qgis-dev/./python/plugins\processing', 'C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.99/apps/qgis-dev/./python', 'C:/Users/geogjo/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python', 'C:/Users/geogjo/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins', 'C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.99/apps/qgis-dev/./python/plugins', 'C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.99\bin\python36.zip', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.99\apps\Python36\DLLs', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.99\apps\Python36\lib', 'C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.99\bin', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.99\apps\Python36', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.99\apps\Python36\lib\site-packages', 'C:/Users/geogjo/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python']

Josh

Comment: I wrote the url with double "\\" after "C:", i.e. `"C:\\Users\geogjo\Downloads\quick_map_services-0.19.3.zip"` no more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know about Quick Map Service itself, but there is the OpenLayers plugin that has been coming default in QGIS for a few versions already.

Aside from that, you can also add basemap services by manually connecting to the providers' WMS, etc. Here are the services for the Google data:

```
<GDAL_WMS>
<!-- Data is subject to term of use detailed at http://code.google.com/intl/nl/apis/maps/terms.html and http://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/help/terms_maps.html -->

<Service name="TMS">
    <!-- <ServerUrl>http://mt.google.com/vt/lyrs=m&amp;x=${x}&amp;y=${y}&amp;z=${z}</ServerUrl> --> <!-- Map -->
     <ServerUrl>http://mt.google.com/vt/lyrs=s&amp;x=${x}&amp;y=${y}&amp;z=${z}</ServerUrl> --> <!-- Satellite -->
    <!-- <ServerUrl>http://mt.google.com/vt/lyrs=y&amp;x=${x}&amp;y=${y}&amp;z=${z}</ServerUrl> --> <!-- Hybrid -->
    <!-- <ServerUrl>http://mt.google.com/vt/lyrs=t&amp;x=${x}&amp;y=${y}&amp;z=${z}</ServerUrl> --> <!-- Terrain -->
    <!-- <ServerUrl>http://mt.google.com/vt/lyrs=p&amp;x=${x}&amp;y=${y}&amp;z=${z}</ServerUrl> --> <!-- Terrain, Streets and Water  -->
</Service>
<DataWindow>
    <UpperLeftX>-20037508.34</UpperLeftX>
    <UpperLeftY>20037508.34</UpperLeftY>
    <LowerRightX>20037508.34</LowerRightX>
    <LowerRightY>-20037508.34</LowerRightY>
    <TileLevel>20</TileLevel>
    <TileCountX>1</TileCountX>
    <TileCountY>1</TileCountY>
    <YOrigin>top</YOrigin>
</DataWindow>
<Projection>EPSG:3857</Projection>
<BlockSizeX>256</BlockSizeX>
<BlockSizeY>256</BlockSizeY>
<BandsCount>3</BandsCount>
<MaxConnections>5</MaxConnections>
<Cache />
</GDAL_WMS>
```

Save this as an XML an import it as a Raster in QGIS, and you should have Google Satellite data. In the Service tag, you can comment the satellite URL and uncomment one of the others for access to Maps, Terrain, etc.

The same can be done for OpenStreetMap, Bing, and other services. Not as practical as having a plugin, but it is a workaround.

Answer (score 2):

It seems it is not yet supported in QGIS 2.99 as stated in QuickMApServices Github:

[QMS for QGIS 3?](https://github.com/nextgis/quickmapservices/issues/143)

> Q: Will QuickMapServices be available for QGIS 3?
>
> A: we don't know yet, pull-requests and support are welcome as usual

Answer (score 1):

The OpenLayers plugin seems indeed not yet available for 2.99.

You can instead use a WMS service ([link](http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/working_with_wms.html)), see for example here: http://www.osm-wms.de/. See also [here](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/WMS#OSM_WMS_Servers) for other examples of OSM WMS Servers.

This example works for me:  http://129.206.228.72/cached/osm?

Answer (score 0):

The Quick Map Services plugin works with QGIS 3.0 and 3.2
In QGIS 3.2, go to Plugins - Manage and Install Plugins and choose "QuickMapServices".
The menu becomes available under Web - QuickMapServices ...