# QGIS 3.0 incompatble with Openlayers and Quicmapservices plugins

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-openlayers-plugin, satellite

Those plugins are very useful to my work, especially the satellite images. Now that I upgraded QGIS to the 3.0 version, they are not available anymore. How can I get back the content of those plugins?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [QGIS 2.99 and Quick Maps Plugin](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/268371/qgis-2-99-and-quick-maps-plugin)

Comment: Also - PLEASE don't install OpenLayers - stick with Quick Map Services alone and you'll experience much less bugs. There's numerous questions all over this stackexchange which are directly caused by bugs in the openlayers plugin.

Answer (score 3):

QGIS 3 is only new and not all plugin developers have had time to port their code yet. Given them some time and they will show up in time.  You are still fine to run both versions at the same time (at least on Windows)